# How to set model in mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a multiple **mat-selec**t element:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="dropDownControl" multiple></mat-select>
```

It contains options elements by type:

```
export interface Employee {
    name: string;
    login: string;
}
```

I have tried to select options using this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dropDownControl.setValue([
        { name: 'aaaa', login: 'aaa_login' },
        { name: 'bbb', login: 'bbb_login' },
   ]);
}
```

But options element in select list was not selected (checked), why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using option value as object. we have to use custom compare function to track obeject identities. Use [compareWith](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) with mat-select.

**compareWith**

> A function to compare the option values with the selected values. If
> it return true the value will get selected in checkbox.

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareWith" [formControl]="dropDownControl" placeholder="Favorite food" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
            {{item.login}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select> 
</mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

```
compareWith(obj1,obj2){
    return obj1 && obj2 && (obj1.login === obj2.login || obj1.name === obj2.name);
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol-tbyrhn)

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation [Angular Material Select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) you'll need to add <mat-option> tags inside of the <mat-select> with [value] set so that the mat-select has something to select from.

Also after to change a form value using setValue you should call `this.dropDownControl.updateValueAndValidity()`